# Must the mean of a product of two random variable with positive mean positive?

Tags: expected-value

I have a form like X(X+Y-1) for X and Y independent random variables. I believe I can show $E[X+Y-1]>0$ and $E[X]>0$. Am I allowed to conclude that also $E[X(X+Y-1)]>0$? I have heard a fkg inequality, but don't know if it can be used in this multiple variables case
Thank you in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E[X(X+Y-1)] = E[X^2] + E[XY] -E[X] \geq E[X]^2 +E[X]E[Y] -E[X] = E[X](E[X] + E[Y] - 1) = E[X] E[X+Y-1] > 0 $$

Comment: Thank you very much, but this inequality does not hold in general?

Comment: I am not sure what situation you refer to when you say "in general". Here we used independence and non-negativity of variance.

Comment: I mean $E[XY]\geq E[X]E[Y]$ if both $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ positive, even if we don't know much about X and Y?

Comment: Note that $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = \mathrm{cov}[X,Y]$, which is limited only by variances of $X, Y$, unless further conditions are imposed.